# Totally bizarre performance of loops and CPS loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, continuations

In order to see whether the continuations-passing style of implementing a loop would be too slow to use in javascript, I created a JS-Perf to test this with the following code:

```
 const ITERATIONS = 10000;

  function NormalLoop() {
      for (var i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
          console.log("loop iteration");
          if (i % 5) {
              console.log("continuing");
              i += 2;
              continue;
          }
          console.log("normally going out");
      }
      console.log("ended loop");
  }

  function WhileTrueLoop() {
      var i = 0;
      while (true) {
          if (i >= ITERATIONS) {
              break;
          }
          console.log("loop iteration");
          if (i % 5) {
              console.log("continuing");
              i += 2;
              i++;
              continue;
          }
          console.log("normally going out");
          i++;
      }
      console.log("ended loop");
  }

  function NonTrampLoop() {
      var i = 0;
      n1(i);
  }

  function n1(i) {
      if (i >= ITERATIONS) {
          n4(i);
          return;
      }
      console.log("loop iteration");
      if (i % 5) {
          console.log("continuing");
          i += 2;
          n3(i)
          return;
      }

      n2(i)
  }

  function n2(i) {
      console.log("normally going out");
      n3(i);
  }

  function n3(i) {
      i = i + 1;
      n1(i);
  }

  function n4() {
      console.log("ended loop");
  }

  function TrampolineSimplistic() {
      var f = function () { return ts1(0) };
      while (f !== null) { f = f(); }
      console.log("ended loop");
  }

  function ts1(i) {
      if (i >= ITERATIONS) {
          return null;
      }
      console.log("loop iteration");
      if (i % 5) {
          console.log("continuing");
          i += 2;
          return function () { return ts3(i); };
      }

      return function () { return ts2(i); };
  }

  function ts2(i) {
      console.log("normally going out");
      return function () { return ts3(i); }
  }

  function ts3(i) {
      i = i + 1;
      return function () { return ts1(i); }
  }

  function TrampolineStreamlined() {

      var f = { cont: t1, i: 0 };
      while (f.cont !== null) { f.cont(f); }
      console.log("ended loop");
  }

  function t1(th) {
      var i = th.i;
      if (i >= ITERATIONS) {
          th.cont = null;
          return;
      }
      console.log("loop iteration");
      if (i % 5) {
          i = i + 2;
          th.i = i;
          th.cont = t3;
          return;
      }

      th.i = i;
      th.cont = t2;
      return;
  }

  function t2(th) {
      var i = th.i;
      console.log("normally going out");
      th.i = i;
      th.cont = t3;
      return;
  }

  function t3(th) {
      var i = th.i;
      i = i + 1;
      th.i = i;
      th.cont = t1;
      return;
  }
```

The five ways are with a standard for loop, a while-true loop, using naive function calls, using trampolining and CPS and using trampolining and CPS preallocating local variables on the heap.

I expected the for loop to be the fastest, followed very closely by the while-true loop, then the trampolining loops taking 2-10x longer than the for loop and the naive function loop to take 10-100x longer than the for-loop.

Now shockingly, the trampolining loop seems to perform fastest on firefox. The slowest loop seems to be the while-true loop! Even the naive function call loop was relatively fast. How can this be when the naive function loop grows the stack proportionally to the number of iterations, whilst the other methods use a constant stack space.

Also the naive trampoline loop allocates a function on the heap several times during every execution. Are the javascript engines just ultra aggressive at optimizing function calls? Have I done something exceptionally stupid in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but I ran some timing on a few browsers.Times are in milliseconds, the number of iterations depend on a rough maximum size in the browser before it errors on the stack size.

```
Firefox
Iterations      : 30000
NormalLoop      : 0
WhileTrueLoop   : 1
NonTrampLoop    : 22
TrampSimplistic : 2
TrampStreamlined: 1

Chrome
Iterations      : 14000
NormalLoop      : 3
WhileTrueLoop   : 2
NonTrampLoop    : 1
TrampSimplistic : 7
TrampStreamlined: 3

Edge
Iterations      : 5000
NormalLoop      : 0
WhileTrueLoop   : 1
NonTrampLoop    : 3
TrampSimplistic : 11
TrampStreamlined: 3

Chrome
Iterations      : 200000
NormalLoop      : 4
WhileTrueLoop   : 4
TrampSimplistic : 68
TrampStreamlined: 14
```

Times in Firefox are pretty consistent, for the other browsers the results vary, I used output I felt was most consistent.

Comment: hmmm I think my browser must be going weird in JSPerf in some way.

Comment: Edge and Firefox meet my expectations, but chrome is totally bizarre. Why on earth is NonTrampLoop performing so well?

Comment: Times are pretty small so I think you should not draw definitive conclusion on these Chrome values. Iterations should be a lot more for better test results but it gives stack overflow errors above 14000.

Comment: If you remove the NonTrampLoop, none of the other methods will stack overflow.

Comment: Did that, results added to answer.